# View Sending an Action to a Controller and returning a query

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, frameworks, cakephp-2.0

I'm kinda noob yet using cakephp, but I would love to know how to use it, for that, I'm trying to develop something pretty simple.

I have a form, that has an input type = 'text' and I wanna search in my database what I just type in this input.

How can I do that ?

I know that I have to get what is inside of my input text and execute a function in my controller that will receive a parameter and execute the query and return the same query to my view.

Other thing that I couldn't do it yet is this:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
```

I wanna change this to cake format, like:

```
echo $this->Form->input('button', array('class' => 'btn', type = 'submit'));
```

but no idea how to add the icon.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the button text like.

```
<?php 

  echo $this->Form->button(
    "<i class='icon-search'></i>", 
    array(
            'class' => 'btn', 
            'type' => 'submit', 
            'escape' => false
  )); // make sure you've use escap = false with html input.

?>
```

and for the search you can define the action like this.

```
<?php

public function search() {
        $conditions = array();
        $params = $this->passedArgs;

        if(isset($params['text_field_name']) && !empty($params['text_field_name'])){
            $conditions['ModelName.text_field_name like'] = $params['text_field_name'].'%';
        }


        $this->Paginate->settings = array(
            'conditions' => $conditions
        );

        $this->set('variable_name', $this->Paginator->paginate());
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this for searching

---- in your .ctp file

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('ModelName'); ?>

<?php echo $this->Form->input('ModelName.search_word'); ?>
<?php  echo $this->Form->submit(" <i class='icon-search'></i> " , array('escape' => false  , 'class' => 'btn' ) ); ?>

<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?> // note that no params for end() method
```

---- in your controller file

```
$searchWord = $this->request->data['ModelName']['search_word'] ;

$this->paginate = array('limit' => 30 ,
            'conditions' => array('OR' => array('ModelName.field1' => "%".$searchWord."%" ,
                                        'ModelName.field2 LIKE' => "%".$searchWord."%" )));

$this->set('searchResults', $this->paginate());
```